# Is the Realtek network driver on Windows Update fixed yet?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-update

Months ago I was experiencing problems with my networking, and was hoping the updated

- Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) Family PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)

driver available from Microsoft on Windows Update would fix the problems.

Instead, after the reboot, the network device failed to start, and the driver had to be rolled back. I'm [not the only person to get this problem](http://tinyurl.com/ye842gw), it even was dealt with by a [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/73112/realtek-lan-driver-problem-win-7).

A co-worker experienced the exact same problem, and we independently came up with the same solution: **hide the updated driver in Windows Update**.

So I've continued to have my network troubles, and I still need an updated driver. Is the version of the Realtek driver on Windows Update fixed yet? I know Microsoft never pulled it down, but maybe it's been up-updated. I really don't want to find out by downloading it.

Can someone else confirm that it's no longer broken - or can someone else be my guinea pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use HW drivers from Windows Update, I always use the vendor's driver.

In the case of your NIC you should look [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).

Comment: To quote my comment on Troggy's answer: i'd prefer the driver that has gone through WHQL - rather than whatever beta they built this morning. But your point is taken.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my experience with specific hardware drivers on Windows Update: Bad.

I really suggest always using the driver from the manufacture website.  Windows update does not always have the latest version and can create some interesting issues. For example, a wonderful hard drive controller driver update I installed once.  Guess which machine did not boot after running that update because of load errors with that driver? That is just one example.

I appreciate Microsoft for trying to get many common drivers integrated into Windows Update.  I just don't trust it anymore and would rather get the most updated version from the manufacture website.

Comment: i'd prefer the driver that has gone through WHQL - rather than whatever beta driver they built this morning. But your point is taken.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the Realtek driver from MS Update when I did a fresh Win7 install on my laptop some while ago. The solution was to use the one from the vendor website...that's usually the best thing to do for any drivers, as MS Update seems to provide old or generic versions.